# Going from Split-tunnel to Full-tunnel VPN on ASA Firewall

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn

I have seen some posts regarding this but I am still a little hazy on the topic.

I have a task to take our VPN solution which is split-tunnel and go full-tunnel with it. I am looking at my config and I see where I would make the tunnel full is under the Policy attributes. Right now it is set to "split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified"

When I go into conf t (config) then group-policy-(Policy_Name) attributes so (config-group-policy)# and do a ? then navigate to split-tunnel-ploicy and do a ? I get these options:

group-policy mode commands/options:
  excludespecified  Exclude only networks specified by
                    split-tunnel-network-list
  tunnelall         Tunnel everything
  tunnelspecified   Tunnel only networks specified by split-tunnel-network-list

Could it really be that simple to change the policy to **tunnelall**? Or has people run into issues where that doesnt work as intended?

Also, I did not implement the VPN solution that is in place now. So where it says tunnelspecified how do I see what the specifications are through CLI?

I am not using the ASDM.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Cisco provides IPSEC and AnyConnect VPN services.
The configuration also varies with IOS version as well.  There was a great change between versions 8.2 and 8.3.

Yes, you can switch it to tunnelall, but there are more issues to be resolved.

The first issue is that devices like printers on the client's local network will no longer be accessible while the VPN is active.

Using excludespecific would allow local networks to be accessed, if you know what they were.  You might use 192.168.0.0/20 to allow for home networks, but there is no guarantee that a users's network will be included.  It also depends on which IP subnets are in use behind the ASA.

The user of the client computer will still expect to access the Internet and will expect the ASA VPN device to provided NAT (or PAT) service to the Internet.

Comment: We do not want users able to access other printers from their work laptops where they have to use our VPN anyconnect client. So that should be OK.

Comment: The thing I am a little confused about is the PAT. So, I have a PAT in place to take the VPN subnet to go through the outside interface. Do I need another PAT in place? Or just the one?

Comment: The source intf is outside, the dest interface is outside, the source is the VPN Subnet pool. Destination is set to any and service is any, then the translatated packet is set to outside.